# Audio Amplifier

Tags: amplifier, audio

I have a 21yr old Pioneer amplifier. Lately I note that 1 channel sounds slightly louder than the other. I switched speakers & effect remained the same, hence the amp is causing this.

What could it b? Time for a re-condition by a technician? I never used it for lenghty periods....sometimes even once or twice a month (moderate volume, perhaps 1 or 2hrs max). What are the effects of time over amps?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It might be your ears?

Comment: Does it have a "volume" control? Older carbon-composition potentiometers often get noisy, or make poor contact with their wiper. Try exercising it vigorously.

Comment: A likely candidate is dried out electrolytic capacitors losing their value - if they are no longer decoupling some point to ground they can reduce the gain of that stage. Measure and replace ... or just replace, on principle.

Comment: What music source do you have connected to the amp and how do you know that that isn't causing the problem?

Comment: The last time I saw an amp with a similar problem, it was an unbalanced Balance pot.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the design of the amplifier it could be that some electrolytic capacitors dried out and they they do no longer decouple the circuits properly. To repair such a problem there are several ways.

1. If you are handy you could replace the electrolytic capacitors your selfs even without understanding the whole circuit. Replace the capacitors with the same value and voltage (voltage might be higher but not lower). Take time and dont make mistakes.
2. If you are not handy or to scared to do this then you can have the capacitors replaced by a skilled technician.

**Warning: As always when working with mains supplied equipment. Work carefully and understand what you are doing. If you not feel secure then stay away from it to prevent health risks or damage to property.**

Answer (score 1):

Besides capacitors drying up, a major cause of this kind of problem is dirty contacts:  Switches, pots, connectors. A good cleaning is in order regardless of the symptoms.